# Random, Non repeating images - LiveCode

Tags: livecode

I'm attempting to display a single image at a time.  I Have a total of about 20.  I need a button, that when pressed it generates a random image, and each time the button is pressed it generates a new random image that hasnt been viewed before.

Basically I want the code to cycle through all the pictures only once,  until all have been seen.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you're generating the images, but assuming you're drawing from an existing pool of source images, here's one way.

```
-- ASSUME SOURCE IMAGES ARE LABELED "image1", "image2", "image3"...

local theList

on mouseUp
   if theList is empty then
      -- CREATE A RANDOM LIST OF NUMBERS
      repeat with N = 1 to 20
         put N & comma after theList
      end repeat
      delete last char of theList
      sort items of theList by random(10000)
   end if
   --
   -- SHOW SOURCE IMAGE IN A CONTAINER IMAGE NAMED "DISPLAY"
   put item 1 of theList into N
   set the text of image "display" to the text of image ("image" & N)
   delete item 1 of theList
end mouseUp
```

Comment: thanks for this.  I'll test it this weekend. I'm displaying images that are imported into the stack, and hidden.